# How to create contract test of Spring RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-test

I have the following CRUD repository annotated with @RepositoryRestResource:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface JPARepository extends CrudRepository<X, Y> {
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('OWNER')")
  Optional<X> findFirstBySpecificField(String specificField);
}
```

How can I create a test responsible for testing the @PreAuthorize annotation without bootstraping the entire spring context and an in-memory database.

In another words I would like to create a contract test using mockMvc to validate that the respective auto-generated endpoint will return 4xx given a specific security condition.

To clarify I have no problem instantiating spring security beans. My problem here is which annotations I should use on my test class to bootstrap only the desired JPA controller.

Comment: 1. You're testing something on a Repository, it's impossible to test without an database. 2.   `spring-data-rest` requires bootstraping data layer and web layer, so there is no difference from boostraping the entire context using `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @yejianfengblue do you know if I could mock my repository method call? I think that way I can test only my weblayer

Comment: If you mock repository method, then you're not testing the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

Comment: If you don't want `@SpringBootTest`, then some classes annotated with `@Configuration` 
 to bootstrap spring context and an in-memory database are required. I can provide such an answer if you modify your requirement.